# Dropdown div not registering when clicked - eventListener and onClick doing nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am making a simple search app in a React function component, the dropdown menu works, and everything looks fine, but when I try to handle the results being clicked, no click registers.

I have used JavaScript to change the the dropdown div's display prop (when the search input is in focus) to block from hidden, and changed the height of it as well with JS. I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

The event handler in useEffect shows nothing, and the handleClick function also does nothing. Please, I have no idea.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});


function handleClick(e) {
  console.log('handleClick fired');
  console.log(e.target);
}

function renderSearchA() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>COMBATANT A</h1>

      <input
        autoFocus
        id="searchA"
        type="text"
        ref={inputA}
        onKeyUp={handleChangeA}
        onFocus={showResultsA}
        onBlur={hideResults}
        placeholder={setPlaceHolder()}
      />
      <div id="results-div" ref={resultsDivA} className="results-shown">
        <ul>{resultsA()}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function showResultsA() {
  if (resultsDivA.current != undefined) {
    resultsDivA.current.style = 'display: block;';
    resultsDivA.current.style = 'height: 0px;';
    resultsDivA.current.style =
      'box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt rgba(255, 108, 35, 0.7)';
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // resultsDiv.current.classList.remove('results');
      resultsDivA.current.classList.add('results-shown');
    }, 200);
  }
}

function resultsMap(x) {
  if (x === 'A' && searchResults != undefined) {
    return searchResults.map((a, b) => {
      console.log(a);
      return (
        <li key={a[2]}>
          <button onClick="handleClick()" className="hero">
            {a[0]}
          </button>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
}

return (
  <SearchDiv>
    <div className="search-a">
      {renderSearchA()}
      <HeroInfo name="a" id="heroA" />
    </div>

    <div className="search-b">
      {renderSearchB()}
      <HeroInfo name="b" id="heroB" className="heroB" />
    </div>
  </SearchDiv>
);
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```css
#searchA {
  /* input */
  width: $ { width };
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  &:focus {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt rgba(255, 108, 35, 0.7);
  }
}

#results-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt rgba(255, 108, 35, 0.7);
}

.results {
  /* div */
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  height: 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
}

.results-shown {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: $ { width };
  display: block;
  /* display: block; */
}
```

Comment: I created this for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sky-ymodb?file=/src/App.js. it seems to work fine?

Comment: `button onClick="handleClick()"` should be `button onClick={handleClick}` for starters. From there you can see what *actually* starts working, or not.

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated